# Effects of Third Party tools on Hypervisor Performance

Tags: virtual-machines, xen, hypervisor

I am using XEN for managing and introspection of VM's. I used DRAKVUF for sake of introspection. XEN provide built in tools for managing VM's. But I want to use LibVIRT for management. I want to know that the installation of third party tools for management will effect performance or flexibility of hypervisor? That will have any effect on my third party Libraries which I use for introspection? I am not expert that's why I asking here and due to my limited knowledge my question may be broad or unclear, so please try your best to address this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libvirt is very lightweight. It's unlikely that it will have any noticeable performance impact, even when collecting metrics continuously via libvirt.

Of course, if your hypervisor is already significantly overcommitted and you are having performance problems, then adding *anything* will make it worse. In this case you should fix the performance issues first.